# Car Battery, storage, home reserve

Tags: batteries, storage, cost

Where I live there is a $.05per kilowatt differential in electricity costs called time of use.  Everyday for at least 12 hours it is at its cheapest. From here I understand a car battery stores about 10 kw.  What would it cost and how would you install something to take advantage of the differential?  Don't want detail just a rough idea if this is anywhere near economical especially if a lot of people started doing it?

Comment: $0.05 is the differential.  What's the base price?

Comment: kW is a unit of power not energy.  No battery stores kW.

Comment: Autotransformer the voltage up a couple of volts, and Grid-Tie it back to them at the higher price.

Answer (score 7):

This doesn't work out well.  Just do the math.

Let's say a car battery has a useful capacity of 50 Ah, just to pick something.  That is the equivalent energy storage of 50 A at 12 V for one hour, which is 600 W for one hour, or 600 Wh, which has a economic advantage of $.03 if stored during the low rate and used during the high.

You didn't say what the absolute cost of the electricity is for the high and low periods, so I'll just pick some roughly plausible numbers to do the calculations with.  Let's say $.13/kWh peak and $.08/kWh off peak.

Now consider this process will have losses.  Temporarily ignoring the economics of installation and maintainence, let's just look at the efficiency your storage system needs to break even.  At efficiency break even, the system would use up $.13 of off-peak power to offset $.13 of peak power.  $.13 of off-peak power is 1.63 kWh, so the break-even efficiency is 1.00 / 1.63 = 62%.  Let's say your AC-DC and DC-AC converters are each 93% efficient, which is very good by today's standards.  That means just the electrical conversion is 86% efficient.  That leaves the battery needing to be 72% efficient.  That's really pushing it for a lead-acid battery.

So bottom line is you need a large investment to capture any real power, since it takes a lot of batteries to store a significant $$ value of energy at $.05/kWh.  And then, the system never delivers any savings anyway due to loosing too much in the conversion and storage processes.  Then there is the issue of deep cycling lead-acid batteries, which car batteries are not meant for.  There are lots of reasons this just doesn't make sense.

From a purely economic point of view figuring no energy losses, it still doesn't make sense.  At $.03 savings per car battery per cycle, it would take 1700 cycles to pay for a $50 battery.  There is absolutely no way a $50 battery that can store 600 Wh is going to last 1700 cycles.